# Mongoose find() never reaches exec block if limit is over a certain number. Seems to be dropping connections out of nowhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
// Find and return all alerts
alertSchema.find(findQuery).limit(limit).sort({
  'last_seen_ts': -1
}).exec((error, values) => {
  if (error) {
    response.status(500).send(error);
    return;
  }
  response.send(values);
});
```

It works perfectly and returns a response until `limit` is set to a number above `101`. After which the code never reaches the .exec block. Looking inside of the `mongod` log I see this:

```
2015-12-29T18:29:00.151-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2015-12-29T18:29:00.450-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64520 #1 (1 connection now open)
2015-12-29T18:29:00.450-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64521 #2 (2 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:29:00.451-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64522 #3 (3 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:29:00.454-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64523 #4 (4 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:29:00.454-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64524 #5 (5 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:34:46.626-0500 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:64520 (4 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:34:46.626-0500 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:64521 (4 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:34:46.626-0500 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:64522 (4 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:34:46.627-0500 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:64523 (2 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:34:46.627-0500 I NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:64524 (0 connections now open)
```

The accepted connections are from when the app first starts, and the ending connections are from setting a limit higher than `101`.

From the `mongo` command line I can make queries that have a limit in the excess of `1000000` so I have no idea what is going on here.

Also for whatever reason the # of connections open varies in the disconnect message. For example here's a run I made immediately after:

```
2015-12-29T18:39:21.656-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64800 #6 (1 connection now open)
2015-12-29T18:39:21.656-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64801 #7 (2 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:39:21.657-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64802 #8 (3 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:39:21.657-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64803 #9 (4 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:39:21.657-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64804 #10 (5 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:39:24.342-0500 I NETWORK  [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:64800 (4 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:39:24.342-0500 I NETWORK  [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:64801 (3 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:39:24.342-0500 I NETWORK  [conn8] end connection 127.0.0.1:64802 (2 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:39:24.342-0500 I NETWORK  [conn9] end connection 127.0.0.1:64803 (2 connections now open)
2015-12-29T18:39:24.342-0500 I NETWORK  [conn10] end connection 127.0.0.1:64804 (2 connections now open)
```

Comment: Are you calling `mongoose.disconnect()` somewhere else before the callback?

Comment: There is a good deal of suspicion here as "end connection" implies that `mongoose.disconnect()` is being called somewhere, and likely before the result has a chance to be returned. Unless you have good reason to do so then you should not be calling this, and then only when you are sure that all operations are complete. Unlisted code appears to be your cause.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I don't even call mongoose.disconnect ever :/

Comment: @BlakesSeven but the puzzling part is that it works perfectly fine for queries with a limit less than 101. For days even.

Comment: @AR7 Aysnc timing is not puzzling at all if you are not actually waiting for completion before disconnecting. That is why such calls are meant to be "within" callbacks of the operations you depend on.

Comment: Try and create a complete, minimal program without any of the express stuff that reproduces the problem and then update your question with that. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: @JohnnyHK yeah I feel the same way. I ran it past a few other people as well and they had no idea what was causing it. If it isn't evident to you guys then I'll have to simplify the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably was a bug in mongoose itself. Problem went away after updating the dependency.